# how to grant the privilege to database using The SQL standards based authorization in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

As per documentation changing ownership to the database by creating a role. 
A role can also be the owner of a database. The "alter database" command can be used to set the owner of a database to a role.
I don`t know further steps how to proceed after changing the owner of data to a role.
 I followed the below syntax  to set the owner ship
ALTER (DATABASE|SCHEMA) database_name SET OWNER [USER|ROLE] user_or_role;

create role ;
Alter database first set owner xyz;

Comment: So what happened when you did this? How do you know it didn't work? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: by following the https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization#SQLStandardBasedHiveAuthorization-RestrictionsonHiveCommandsandStatements by changing the ownership of the database to role, we can grant the privileges. I followed these steps

create role a;

ALTER DATABASE x SET OWNER ROLE a;

can any help to proceed further steps towards the granting privileges to database x;

Thanks a lot.